# Can I undo the last few transaction, or revert to yesterday in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb, revert

I have an SQL file containing several commands, when I need to make a correction to my application database that the application can't yet do, I use DBVis to select and execute the command I need (e.g. to delete an incorrect entry). Problem is, the button to run the whole page is right next to the button to run a selected command. So I just dropped and re-created my table, losing all my data. Is there a way to undo this?
I'm looking to either 'undo' each command until I get back to the right place, or revert back to yesterday, where I know everything was correct.
Thanks!

Comment: No. You need to restore a backup of your database, if you took one sometimes.

Comment: Well, I'm boned.... Lesson Learned!

Comment: Lession in UI design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can if...

- your administration tool  did set `autocommit=OFF` by default, you can
  just execute a `ROLLBACK` (or just shutdown your administration tool)
- If latter doesn't work, check if your binary log was enabled, and restore with mysqlbin log tool
- If none of the above mentioned solution works, use your (probably not existent) backup for restoring